# Slider with two images at a time

Tags: plugins

I need an images slider that supports adding two images next to each other and to show them at the same time with prev & next option,
I need to be able to change to the next two images when a user clicks on next & prev ,
I will use this to display two images of [before and after hair cut].

Comment: Why not just include the before & after images into 1 image?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Slick slider handles displaying multiple slides at once nicely. You can also set it to display different number of slides at different breakpoints for responsive layouts.

https://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/